# PyQt5: при изменении размера/движении виджет не успевает до конца отрисоваться, как это исправить? (Eng in description)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Вот видео происходящего (при изменении размера/движении появляются белые полосы/виджет не успевает отрисоваться)
Here is a video of what is happening (when resizing / moving, white stripes appear / the widget does not have time to draw)

Video (without download):
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ZoEL0EWCeDgB6w

UPD:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Button(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setText("Кнопка")
        self.resize(200, 50)
        self.move(100, 100)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30); color: white; border: 2px solid rgb(215, 150, 100); border-radius: 10px")

        self.size_anim = QVariantAnimation()
        self.size_anim.setStartValue(self.size())
        self.size_anim.setEndValue(QSize(150, 30))
        self.size_anim.setDuration(100)
        self.size_anim.valueChanged.connect(self.resize)

        self.move_anim = QVariantAnimation()
        self.move_anim.setStartValue(self.pos())
        self.move_anim.setDuration(100)
        self.move_anim.valueChanged.connect(self.move)
    
        
        

    def mousePressEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent):
        if e.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.size_anim.setDirection(QVariantAnimation.Direction.Forward)
            self.size_anim.start()

            self.move_anim.setDirection(QVariantAnimation.Direction.Forward)
            x = self.parent().mapFromGlobal(self.cursor().pos()).x() - self.width() / 4
            y = self.parent().mapFromGlobal(self.cursor().pos()).y() - self.height() / 4
            self.move_anim.setStartValue(self.pos())
            self.move_anim.setEndValue(QPoint(x, y))
            self.move_anim.start()
        
            self.dragPos = e.globalPos()
            e.accept()
        return super().mousePressEvent(e)


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent):
        if e.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.size_anim.setDirection(QVariantAnimation.Direction.Backward)
            self.size_anim.start()
        return super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent):
        pos = self.pos() + e.globalPos() - self.dragPos
        self.move(pos)
        self.dragPos = e.globalPos()
        e.accept()


    def resize(self, size: QSize, *args):
        return super().resize(size, *args)



class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Тест анимации")
        self.resize(1280, 720)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50)")

        self.button = Button(self)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    
    window = Window()
    window.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: вот, добавил подопытный код)

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас получается не так. У меня ваш пример выполняется так, как в нем написано.

Comment: я на видео показал, что при изменении размера/движении не весь стиль хорошо отрисовывается, например, появляется белая область у background'a (в первом случае) и криво отображается кнопка (во втором случае)...
я хочу сделать так, чтобы всё правильно отрисовывалось, когда я провожу какие-то махинации с виджетами, чтобы пейнтер всё успевал, а не выдавал такие позорные баги)))